# Are these possible LeveneTest results?

Tags: r, variance, p-value, reporting, levenes-test

I have experimental data of response times that differ according to the factor `TrialType`: `Regular` or `Random`. I also have two groups, `A` and `B`, which I expect to behave the same (they were created for counterbalancing purposes).

I want to test the equality of variance assumption in my data. I am pretty sure the variances are *not* equal, but I want to show it with a test anyway.

My data is contained in a long data.frame called `AB`:

```
summary(AB)
Block          Trial         TrialType      Subject          variable      value       
 Block1:1930   Min.   :  1.0   Random :5889   Length:9852        RT:9852   Min.   : 348.0  
 Block2:1974   1st Qu.:128.0   Regular:3963   Class :character             1st Qu.: 595.0  
 Block3:1982   Median :252.0                  Mode  :character             Median : 692.0  
 Block4:1983   Mean   :251.9                                               Mean   : 765.7  
 Block5:1983   3rd Qu.:376.0                                               3rd Qu.: 834.0  
           Max.   :500.0                                               Max.   :4412.0  
 Group   
 A:4929  
 B:4923
```

I tried the Levene Test using both Group and TrialType as grouping factor (the second argument):

```
leveneTest(AB$value,AB$Group)

leveneTest(AB$value,AB$TrialType)
```

As you can see, I am still unclear whether the second argument should be `Group` (`A` and `B`) or `TrialType` (`random` and `regular`). I just tried both.

For group, the p-value it was 8.479e-11, and for TrialType, p was 2.413e-12. Also, the degrees of freedom for both cases is 1, and the F values are very high: 42,23 for Group and 49.24 for TrialType. So the 3 values I am getting from these tests seem highly unusual. Therefore I suspect I might be doing something wrong. Any comments or/and help is much appreciated. Also, any tips on how to report these results would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember it's the residuals from your model that should be distributed with equal variances. You want to use Group & TrialType *together* as grouping factors: `leveneTest(value~TrialType*Group, data=AB)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification @Scortchi. Would you happen to know how to report this? Is it the same as with other p-value reports? e.g. F(df)= , p < 0.001 ?

Comment: Depends on the readers of your report & the level of detail you want to go into; but describing the test & giving the observed value of the test statistic & p-value should be fine in general.